# How can I create a file with FileSystem API?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

```
 {

    "description": "Test Description",
   "icons":{
     "16": "images/ticket_16.png",
     "128": "images/ticket_128.png"
   },

   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Test App",

   "version": "1.0",

   "app":{
     "background":{
       "scripts": ["background.js"]
     }
   },
   "permissions": ["fileSystem",{"fileSystem": ["write", "retainEntries", "directory"]},"unlimitedStorage" ]

 }
```

background.js;

```
 chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
     chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
     'width': 1024,
     'height': 768
     });
 });

 window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;

 function errorHandler(e) {
     console.log(e.name + ": " + e.message);
 }

 function onInitFs(fs) {


     fs.root.getFile('C:\\Users\\jt\\Desktop\\test\\a.txt', {create: true},      function(fileEntry) {
         //fileEntry.isFile === true;
         fileEntry.name == 'a.txt';
         fileEntry.fullPath == 'C:\\Users\\jt\\Desktop\\test\\a.txt';

         fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {

             fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
                 console.log('Write completed.');
             };

             fileWriter.onerror = function(e) {
                 console.log('Write failed: ' + e);
             };



             if (!window.BlobBuilder && window.WebKitBlobBuilder)
                 window.BlobBuilder = window.WebKitBlobBuilder;

              var bb = new Blob(['Lorem Ipsum'], {type: 'text/plain'});

             console.log("bb size:"+bb.size);

             fileWriter.write(bb); 
         }, errorHandler);
     }, errorHandler);
 }

 window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 5*1024*1024, onInitFs,errorHandler);
```

Hi,

I want to create a specific directory text file. This practice will only be used by our customers.

The codes I gave above do not create the file I want.
When I did not specify the directory, the file was created. But I do not know where it is.
What I need is to create a .txt file for the directory I want.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

//Update

```
 chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type: 'openFile'}, function(entry) {
     if (!entry) {
       console.log("Cancelled");
       return;
     }

     chrome.fileSystem.getDisplayPath(entry, function(path) {
         entry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {

             fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
                 console.log('Write completed.');
             };

             fileWriter.onerror = function(e) {
                 console.log('Write failed: ' + e);
             };

             if (!window.BlobBuilder && window.WebKitBlobBuilder)
                 window.BlobBuilder = window.WebKitBlobBuilder;

        var bb = new Blob(['Lorem Ipsum'], {type: 'text/plain'});

             console.log("bb size:"+bb.size);

             fileWriter.write(bb); 
         }, errorHandler);

     });
 });
```

With the code I gave in the update section, I can add data to the selected file.
The first code I gave is correct, but I am having a problem with the directory.

I get this error;

```
 NotFoundError: A requested file or directory could not be found at the time an operation was processed.
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem

Comment: I already read this doc. But im not fix.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the demo app which uses FileSystem

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/filesystem-access

and here step by step guide:

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-support

Comment: I read this document but not helpful. I get this error;
NotFoundError: A requested file or directory could not be found at the time an operation was processed.
Can you help me?